Can I place objects along a line with Geometry Nodes and have them rotated along the line?
I am trying to use Geometry Nodes to place square "pillars" along a wall. This is what I have now:

I modeled a pillar as an object named "Cube" (...it's temporary :) ), and then I applied this Geometry Nodes modifier, passing as a parameter (Object) the line you see highlighted in orange:

Please ignore the "Align rotation to vector" node: it's from a failed attempt.
As you can see in the first image, the pillars are all oriented in a fixed direction, that matches the original's rotation. What I want is the pillars to "follow along" the line, i.e., each one has two faces that are parallel to the wall.
I'm a beginner with Geometry Nodes, so I'm open to wildly different approaches :)
PS: Ideally, since I hope to reuse this modifier elsewhere, the modifier should have a boolean to allow either the behavior I've described ("follow along") and the one you see depicted ("don't follow along").

If you convert the mesh line that is receiving the instances into a curve and then put that into a Curve to Points then it it will automatically output a Normal, Tangent and Rotation outputs derived from the curve direction values. If you plug the Rotation output in into the Rotation on the Instance on Points rotation it should get you pretty close.

@Jakemoyo Thank you, that's what I need! Isolating the Z rotation gets me what I want. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

If you convert the mesh line that is receiving the instances into a curve and then put that into a Curve to Points then it it will automatically output a Normal, Tangent and Rotation outputs derived from the curve direction values.

If you plug the Rotation output in into the Rotation on the Instance on Points rotation it should get you pretty close. You can tweak the rotation after you get the instances aligned with a Rotate Instances Node.
Full graph.

Result.

